# split and combining files

Tags: ubuntu, macos-highsierra, combine

I am using Mac, need to upload a very large zip file. If I split that using Mac OS command line, and upload files to Ubuntu Server. Can I combine that on Ubuntu?

In short, does split command works 100% the same on ubuntu and mac os?

Comment: How exactly do you split the file?

Comment: like 'split -n5 linux-lite.zip'

Comment: I'd use `-b` to specify the size, looking for 1000 lines in a zip file might behave strangely, as zip is a binary format.

Comment: I have tried 'split largefile.zip', uploaded chunk files on ubuntu server, combine them using 'cat x* > new.zip' but that new zip is not extracting, not working. Looking for the solution.

Comment: Is `zipsplit` an option?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this using CentOS and MacOS. As choroba suggested, using the `-b` option will cut the files into equal-sized pieces without regard to the presence of newlines in the input. I cut a binary zip file into pieces on MacOS, copied the pieces over to CentOS, and used `cat * > out.zip` to re-generate the zip file. The resulting file on CentOS was identical to the original file on MacOS. Results with Ubuntu instead of CentOS should be the same.